# WPF - Listview not displaying sorted values correctly

Tags: wpf, sorting, listview

I have to use a Listview instead of a Datagrid for a WPF project, so I have to implement sorting manually. The underlying list is sorting correctly, but the display is not.

My lists are set up as follows:

```
ObservableCollection<myObject> MasterList = new ObservableCollection<myObject>();
ObservableCollection<myObject> SortedList = new ObservableCollection<myObject>();
guiList.ItemsSource = SortedList;
```

I used [this](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-how-to-column-sorting/) tutorial to set up sorting, and everything seems fine, but the GUI list does not sort in the order I would expect. This is a small example of the code where the sorting is done:

```
private void UpdateList()
{
    switch (columnToSort)
    {
        case ColumnSort.ID:
        if (sortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
        {
            SortedList = new ObservableCollection<myObject>(MasterList.OrderBy(o => o.ID));
        }
        else
        {
            SortedList = new ObservableCollection<myObject>(MasterList.OrderByDescending(o => o.controllerID));
        }

    break;
}
```

When I debug the code above, the SortedList is in the correct order, so I can't figure out why the guiList is not displaying in that same order. I even tried:

```
guiList.ItemsSource = null;
guiList.ItemsSource = SortedList;
```

After every update just to "reset" the guiList, but that still doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant tell exactly why your code above isn't working as it seems to be working for me, however you should consider using a [CollectionView](http://www.wpftutorial.net/dataviews.html), that way you don't need to maintain a separate collection just for sorted objects.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, that's what I ended up using; marked as answered. Thanks!